# Как залогиниться в gmail.com с помощью Selenium Webdriver +Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[image: Страницу ввода логина прохожу удачно, а дальше такая страница следует]

Менял профили и для Хрома и для Мозилы - не помогает, как будто защита стоит у них против автоматизированного ПО. Т.к. вручную все получается и такая страница не выскакивает.

```
 public static WebDriver configureFirefox() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\WebDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    ProfilesIni profile1 = new ProfilesIni();
    FirefoxProfile myProfile = profile1.getProfile("default");

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, myProfile);
    return new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
}

public static WebDriver configureChrome() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/");

    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

    return new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
}

private final String linkEnterEmailCssLocator = "a.gmail-nav__nav-link.gmail-nav__nav-link__sign-in";

public StartMailPage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}

public StartMailPage open() {
    this.open("https://www.google.com/intl/ru/gmail/about/#");
    return new StartMailPage(driver);
}

public LoginPage clickEnterEmail(){
    this.findByCss(linkEnterEmailCssLocator).click();
    return new LoginPage(driver);
}

/*    @FindBy(how = How.CSS, css = "span.RveJvd.snByac")
WebElement buttonNext;*/

private final String inputLoginIdLocator = "identifierId";
//private final String inputReserveEmailIdLocator = "recoveryIdentifierId";
private final String inputPasswordCssLocator = "#password > div.aCsJod.oJeWuf > div > div.Xb9hP > input";
private final String changeUserLinkIdLocator = "identifierLink";

private final String buttonNext = "span.RveJvd.snByac";

public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}


public SecurityPage logIn(String log, String pass) {
    this.findById(changeUserLinkIdLocator).click();

    this.findById(inputLoginIdLocator).sendKeys(log);

    this.findByCss(buttonNext).click();
    this.findById(inputPasswordCssLocator).sendKeys(pass);
   // js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", buttonNext);
   // buttonNext.click();
    this.findByCss(buttonNext).click();
    return new SecurityPage();
}


@BeforeTest
public void configureBrowser(){
    firefox = WebDriverFactory.configureFirefox();
    firefox.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

  @AfterTest
public void closeBrowser() {
    firefox.quit();
}

    @Test
public void logIn(){
    new StartMailPage(firefox).open().clickEnterEmail().logIn("login","password");

}
```

Comment: А вам обязательно через браузер? Нормальный SMTP/POP3/IMAP для нормального доступа к почте не годится для ваших задач?

Comment: потому что браузер под автотестами запускается чистым и без профилей. поэтому пользователя не видит

Comment: Это тестовое задание! Selenium обязательно.
Я загружал и с профилями, не помогает!

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось в ГУГЛе нужно кликать только на не закрытые элементы, иначе срабатывает их защита и требуется вост. пароля!

Comment: Сообщение было опубликовано в качестве ответа, но оно не содержит ответа на вопрос. Сообщение может быть правкой, комментарием, другим вопросом, но, возможно, его стоит просто удалить.